# C++ How to convert unicode character to int

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, unicode

I want to convert Unicode characters (Persian) to int. 
Based on [this](https://unicode-table.com/en/#0622) list, the Unicode number of `'آ'` is `U+0622`.

Suppose i want to give `U+0622` as integer value. I wrote this piece of code:

```
unsigned int Alef = (unsigned int)'آ';
std::cout << Alef << std::endl;
```

output:

> 63

Correct Answer is 1570 and as you see the output is wrong. I guess it only converts first byte of Unicode Character.

How do i convert that Unicode character to give correct answer?

Comment: You've put the character as a char literal, so it will be converted to a byte by the compiler I believe.

Comment: If you try to *print* `'آ'`, will it print correctly? Because `'آ'` is really a multi-byte character and how those are handled is implementation (compiler) specific. Try using wide-character literals like `L'آ'` or Unicode-character literals like `u'آ'` or `U'آ'` (for 16 and 32 bit variants respectively).

Comment: Which compiler do you use? G++ gives 55458.

Comment: You could also be saving the file in an ASCII format rather than Unicode, in which case the character might have the first byte chopped off producing a '?' which is 63 in ASCII

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try expressing the character as a `wchar` literal:

```
unsigned int Alef = (unsigned int) L'آ';
std::cout << Alef << std::endl;
```

But make sure you're saving as Unicode, nano, for example, converts the 'آ' to a '?' before saving. As would Notepad on Windows I think?

Also to add to my answer, you should write Unicode characters to `std::wcout` not `std::cout` as cout is for single byte chars and wcout is for `wchar` types.

EDIT: Notepad does save as Unicode